# Add edges to a DAG to maximize increase in number of connected vertices

Tags: ds.algorithms

Let $G$ be a Directed Acyclic Graph.

$$C(G) = \bigl|\{(u,v):u,v\in V(G),v \text{ reachable from } u\}\bigr|$$

Goal is to add $k$ edges in a DAG such that for the new $G'$, $C(G')$ is maximized.

My idea is as follows. DAG is given so, we can assume that it is bipartite graphs with $S$ called source and $T$ will be called as sinks. $(|S||T|)^{k}$ time algorithm seems working as per my calculation. A vertex is called as source if all edges it have are outgoing and a vertex is called sink if all edges it have are incoming.

What is the fastest algorithm for this problem?

Comment: Must $G'$ also be a DAG?

Comment: @ Yonatan N  Not necessarily to be a DAG.

Comment: The problem can be shown to be NP-hard using a pretty simple reduction from Max-$k$-Cover (plus maybe a disjoint path of length $n^3$ or longer). Unfortunately, I can't provide details at the moment.

Comment: @ Yonatan N  Yes, I am looking for faster algorithm.

Comment: In the post, what is $k$?  What is "the matching of the DAG"?  If the problem is NP-hard, what are you looking for? A poly-time approximation alg?  A sub-exponential time algorithm?  Please edit the post to clarify these issues.  As it stands it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @Neal Young I have modified the question.

Comment: So you have in mind that $(S, T)$ is a partition of the vertex set of the input graph, and every (existing) directed edge goes from $S$ to $T$?

Comment: @ Neal Young  Yes.

Comment: Do you require the algorithm to return the exact optimum?  Or are you also interested in approximation algorithms?  If exact, what would you consider "faster"?  Your proposed algorithm takes time something like $n^{2k+O(1)}$ where $n=|S|+|T|$.  Would you consider, say, $n^{k+O(1)}$ to be "faster"?  Or might you be interested in parameterized complexity, e.g. an algorithm running in time $f(k) n^{O(1)}$ for some function $k$?  A-priori, any of these kinds of algorithms might be possible, so "fastest" is not really well-defined.

Comment: @A_Theory, How it is possible that (S,T) is a "partition" of vertex set of input graph? A DAG may not always be a Bipartite graph...for example, take a path of length 2. It is DAG but not a bipartite graph with S and T as partition...

Comment: @Inuyashayagami, I believe OP is defining the problem that way (all edges in the given graph must go from S to T, where (S, T) is a partition of the vertex set).  But I agree OP's current description is unclear.

Comment: It's not clear to me that the content after "my idea is as follows:" is part of the problem description. It begins with 'Let G be a DAG' so there are potentially vertices which are not sinks or sources. A greedy algorithm would be to build a DFS tree and to add an edge from a leave to the root for the leaf that is furthest from any ancestor which has a path back to the root. That is, one could run a test for strong connectivity and then add edges opportunistically. Again, it isn't clear as to whether OP wants an exact algorithm after someone claims NP hardness and he wants it faster.